# using vb6 dll in .net desktop application on 64 bit windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, dll, vb6

I got a problem with old vb dll that I use in my Desktop .net 3.5 application. I recently got a new computer that runs 64 bit windows 7 while the old one was 32. And I'm getting this exception when creating instance of class from the dll.

The name of the dll starts with Interop.DllName.

This is the exception:

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {C198B362-6AE8-4DC3-A3E9-5DA5E60B326F} failed due to the following error: 80040154.

There is no problem with registering the dll on the registry using regsvr32 but when I'm trying to find the dll using RegDllView I can't find it.

Thanx for the assistance!

Comment: You cannot use a 32-bit dll within a 64-bit process.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to ensure that you .Net application target platform is set to x86 or the program will run in a 64bit process and will not be able to load a 32bit dll

Comment: In that case you might find that one of the dependencies is missing.  See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/88a6ea68-f476-4231-822f-27fabe59f458/ for an issue that sounds identical.